# If the sum of four squares is a square, what is the equivalent sum of three squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares

Let’s say I have
\begin{align}  \tag{1}
x_1^2 = y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2+y_4^2,
\end{align}
where all the numbers are integers, and $x_1$ is odd. Evidently, $x_1^2$ is not of the form $4^k(8m+7)$, and so [by well-known classical results] it can be written as the sum of three squares.

Is there an established transformation/parameterization to turn $x_1^2=y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2+y_4^2$ into $x_1^2=z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2$, where the $z_i$ are integer (or rational) functions of the $y_i$?

I know Bradley et al. give formulas for (1), e.g.
\begin{align}
 x_1 &= (uz+vy+wx)^2+m^2(m^2+x^2+y^2+z^2+u^2+v^2+w^2), \\
 y_1 &= (uz+vy+wx)^2-m^2(m^2+x^2+y^2+z^2-u^2-v^2-w^2),  \\
 y_2 &= 2m(um^2+uz^2+xvm-ywm+xwz+yvz), \\
 y_3 &= 2m(vm^2+vy^2+zwm-xum+zuy+xwy), \\
 y_4 &= 2m(wm^2+wx^2+yum-zvm+yvx+zux),
\end{align}
and Catalan gave the complete solution for the [2.1.3] equation, so I’ll do the grunt work if necessary… I was just hoping this particular wheel was already invented.

Comment: Can we just take one variable to zero in the formula, e.g., $y_2=0$? With $m=0$? Then $x_1^2=y_1^2+0^2+0^2$ is a sum of three squares.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Well, yes, that’s the trivial solution… Solving the other factor of $y_2$ as zero (i.e., $m \ne 0$) is a promising approach, though. Thanks!

Comment: You could try to make some other $y_i=0$, without having the trivial solution. Say, $m=1$ and $1^2+x^2+y^2+z^2-u^2-v^2-w^2=0$.

Comment: $21^2$ can be written as the sum of four distinct non-zero squares in $10$ ways, and as the sum of three distinct non-zero squares in $5$ ways. What results are you looking for in that case?

Comment: @DanielMathias: Any formula showing the transformation will probably suffice!

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Not unexpectedly, setting  $y_2=0$ and working the rest out yields Catalan’s formula with an extra [common] multiplier.

Comment: My comment was intended to suggest that there is no general formula.

Comment: @DanielMathias: I know what your comment was intended to suggest… but there ARE general formulas: for example, taking Bradley’s 2.4.4 complete solution and setting $y_4=0$, we get a general formula for the 2.4.3 Diophantine equation $X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2+X_4^2=Y_1^2+Y_2^2+Y_3^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Comment: We may try this idea; suppose we have two Pythagorean triples:

$a^2+b^2=c^2$

$d^2+e^2=f^2$

Multiplying both sides we get:

$(ad)^2+(ae)^2+(bd)^2+(be)^2=(cf)^2=(af)^2+(bf)^2=(af)^2+(be)^2+(bd)^2$

But we do not want identical terms on both sides, so we have to find numbers like $s$ and $t$ such that:

$A=(be)^2+(bd)^2=s^2+t^2$

It leads to this question : are there numbers(not necessarily perfect square) like $A$ which can be written as the sum of two squares in two different forms? We can try this analytically; suppose our two triples are of the following forms:

$(4i)^2+(4i^2-1)^2=(4i^2+1)^2$

$(2i+1)^2+[2i(i+1)]^2=[2i(i+1)+1]^2$

After multiplying both sides we finally get:

$A=[8i^3(i+1))]^2+[2(i^2+i)(4i^2-1)]^2=s^2+t^2$

Now we have a Diophantine equation with three unknown to solve.